# spring-data-mongodb giving mongodb authentication exception

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-java

I am using

- Mongodb 3.2.0
- Mongo-Java-Driver 3.2.0
- spring-data-mongodb 1.9.2

and referred to this link [accessing-mongodb-with-authentication](http://javarticles.com/2016/01/accessing-mongodb-with-authentication.html),
and created user in myDb by logging as admin to admin database.

```
    db.createUser({user: "admin",pwd: "password",roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "myDb" } ]});
     db.auth('admin','password');
      db.grantRolesToUser("admin",[{ role: "dbAdmin", db: "myDb" }])
```

for setting up mongodb authentication the link example worked. The spring-data configuration is :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate"
    id="mongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo" />
    <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="myDb" />
             <constructor-arg name="userCredentials" ref="mongoCredentials"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean"
    id="mongo">
    <property name="host" value="localhost" />
    <property name="port" value="27017" />
</bean>
 
 <bean id="mongoCredentials" class="org.springframework.data.authentication.UserCredentials">
            <constructor-arg name="username" value="admin" />
            <constructor-arg name="password" value="password"/>
     
</bean>
```

In my java code :

```
    public static void main(String[]s)
   {
  ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
            
            
dao.TemplateDao dao = (dao.TemplateDao)context.getBean("dao");
dao.testingSales();
 }
     public void testingSales() {
    Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
             Criteria c= null;
     Aggregation agg = null;
     Aggregation agg2 = null;
          System.out.println(mongoTemplate.getCollectionNames());

 }
```

It throws this Exception:

```
         org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Command failed with error 13: 'not authorized on myDb to execute command { listCollections: 1, cursor: { batchSize: 0 } }' on server localhost:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "not authorized on myDb to execute command { listCollections: 1, cursor: { batchSize: 0 } }", "code" : 13 }; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 13: 'not authorized on journaldev to execute command { listCollections: 1, cursor: { batchSize: 0 } }' on server localhost:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "not authorized on myDb to execute command { listCollections: 1, cursor: { batchSize: 0 } }", "code" : 13 }
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:107)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:2114)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:448)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.getCollectionNames(MongoTemplate.java:1654)
at dao.TemplateDaoImpl.testingSales(TemplateDaoImpl.java:4812)
at dao.impl.TemplateDaoImpl.main(TemplateDaoImpl.java:340)
     
   Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 13: 'not authorized on myDb to execute command { listCollections: 1, cursor: { batchSize: 0 } }' on server localhost:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "not authorized on myDb  to execute command { listCollections: 1, cursor: { batchSize: 0 } }", "code" : 13 }
at com.mongodb.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:86)
at com.mongodb.connection.CommandProtocol.execute(CommandProtocol.java:119)
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:159)
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:286)
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:173)
at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:215)
at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:206)
at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:112)
at com.mongodb.operation.ListCollectionsOperation$1.call(ListCollectionsOperation.java:177)
at com.mongodb.operation.ListCollectionsOperation$1.call(ListCollectionsOperation.java:172)
at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:239)
at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:212)
at com.mongodb.operation.ListCollectionsOperation.execute(ListCollectionsOperation.java:172)
at com.mongodb.operation.ListCollectionsOperation.execute(ListCollectionsOperation.java:80)
at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:773)
at com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:760)
at com.mongodb.OperationIterable.iterator(OperationIterable.java:47)
at com.mongodb.OperationIterable.forEach(OperationIterable.java:70)
at com.mongodb.MappingIterable.forEach(MappingIterable.java:50)
at com.mongodb.MappingIterable.into(MappingIterable.java:60)
at com.mongodb.DB.getCollectionNames(DB.java:253)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$14.doInDB(MongoTemplate.java:1656)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$14.doInDB(MongoTemplate.java:1654)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:446)
... 3 more
```

Regards

Kris

Comment: Have you tried connecting to mongo via mongo shell using the userid and password? Were you successfully authenticated in mongo shell?

Comment: I tried with mongo shell, its working fine, and then with mongodb-java-driver its working fine, but with spring-data-mongodb, this issue pops up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use the below application context and try to connect to MongoDB. It should work. The main thing missing in your application context is "AuthenticationMechanism" (i.e. value is SCRAM-SHA-1). Just to add the correct authentication mechanism, we may need to take this approach.

I have reproduced the issue and resolved it using the below context file. Hopefully, this should fix the issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="mongoSeedListID" class="java.util.ArrayList">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <ref bean="mongoSeedlID" />
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mongoSeedlID" class="com.mongodb.ServerAddress">
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" name="host"
            value="localhost" />
        <constructor-arg type="int" name="port" value="27017" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="mongoCredentialListID" class="java.util.ArrayList">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <ref bean="mongoCredentialID" />
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mongoCredentialID" class="com.mongodb.MongoCredential">
        <constructor-arg name="mechanism"
            value="#{T(com.mongodb.AuthenticationMechanism).SCRAM_SHA_1}" />
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" name="userName"
            value="admin" />
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" name="source"
            value="myDb" />
        <constructor-arg type="char[]" name="password" value="password" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="mongoClientID" class="com.mongodb.MongoClient">
        <constructor-arg ref="mongoSeedListID" />
        <constructor-arg ref="mongoCredentialID" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="simpleMongoDbFactoryID"
        class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory">
        <constructor-arg ref="mongoClientID" />
        <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="myDb" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean"
        id="mongo">
        <property name="host" value="localhost" />
        <property name="port" value="27017" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="simpleMongoDbFactoryID" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: This results in the same exception : Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 13: 'not authorized on myDb to execute command { listCollections: 1, cursor: { batchSize: 0 } }' on server localhost:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "not authorized on myDb to execute command { listCollections: 1, cursor: { batchSize: 0 } }", "code" : 13 }

Comment: Hi @notionquest, please lemme know the version of Mongodb you are using, I am using Mongodb-3.2 and spring-data-mongodb-1.9.2

Comment: I am using the same version (both mongodb and spring data mongodb) as well.

Comment: I have added a solution. Please take a look.

Comment: I am using windows 8, its not working, which OS are you using?

Comment: what error are you getting now? I am using windows 7. I think the Mongo authentication mechanism shouldn't be related to windows version.

Answer (score 5):

```
I think maybe the mongodb's authorization has little hard to understand.
This works for me,

    @Configuration
public class MongoConfig {

    @Value("${mongo.host}")
    private  String host;

    @Value("#{new Integer('${mongo.port}')}")
    private  Integer port;

    @Value("${mongo.database}")
    private  String database;

    @Value("${mongo.username}")
    private  String username;

    @Value("${mongo.password}")
    private  String password;

    public @Bean MongoClientFactoryBean mongoDbFactory() throws Exception {
        MongoClientFactoryBean clientFactoryBean = new MongoClientFactoryBean();
        clientFactoryBean.setHost(host);
        clientFactoryBean.setPort(port);
        MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createScramSha1Credential(username, database, password.toCharArray());
        clientFactoryBean.setCredentials(new MongoCredential[]{credential});
        return clientFactoryBean;
    }

    public @Bean MongoTemplate mongoTemplate(Mongo mongo) throws Exception {
        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongo, database);
        return mongoTemplate;

    }
}

---------------------------------
mongo.host=127.0.0.1
mongo.port=27017
mongo.username=hisoka
mongo.password=welcome
mongo.database=test
----------------------------
Just in mongod cmd create user hisoka for db test,
db.createUser({"user":"hisoka","pwd":"welcome","roles":[{role:"readWrite",db:"test"}]});
------------------------------
Take look in mongoChef, the mongodb auth info:
{ 
    "_id" : "test.hisoka", 
    "user" : "hisoka", 
    "db" : "test", 
    "credentials" : {
        "SCRAM-SHA-1" : {
            "iterationCount" : NumberInt(10000), 
            "salt" : "tfXYRbCj6N433PFWJzwarA==", 
            "storedKey" : "pMnNVX7Co7AY7Q4b/dtq18IQfeE=", 
            "serverKey" : "x8vUt590SYVxqW2PW6DA849iTgE="
        }
    }, 
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "readWrite", 
            "db" : "test"
        }
    ]
}
```