# mongo db authentication error with spring (Query failed with error code 13 and error message)

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I am getting following error while trying to find records from mongodb collection.

```
org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Query failed with error code 13 and error message 'not authorized for query on ssprod.logger_user_activities' on server beta.redbus.co:27017; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 13 and error message 'not authorized for query on ssprod.logger_user_activities' on server beta.redbus.co:27017
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:96)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:2011)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1894)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1705)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1688)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:601)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.findAll(SimpleMongoRepository.java:268)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.findAll(SimpleMongoRepository.java:193)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.findAll(SimpleMongoRepository.java:47)
```

my spring configuration file looks like below

```
     <mongo:repositories
              base-package="psl.service.infra.loggerx.server" mongo-template-ref="mongoTemplate"/>

<bean id="mongo" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean">
    <property name="host" value="${mongo.host}"/>
  </bean>

      <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="mongo"/>
        <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="ssprod"/>
        <constructor-arg name="userCredentials" ref="mongoCredentials"/>
      </bean>

      <bean id="mongoCredentials" class="org.springframework.data.authentication.UserCredentials">
        <constructor-arg name="username" value="${mongo.username}"/>
        <constructor-arg name="password" value="${mongo.password}" />
      </bean>



    </beans>
```

Credentials are correct and user has read and write access.Kindly help.

Comment: Has your issue resolved? Just wondering whether the below solution helped or you are still facing any issue?

Comment: Ya issue got resolved. actually in my pom.xml there was some conflict between mongo jars.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that the "AuthenticationMechanism" (i.e. value is SCRAM-SHA-1) is missing in the Spring context. Please refer the below link and change the Spring context file accordingly.

Even after changing the context if you get this error, please paste the error with the latest context file.

[Refer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38605270/spring-data-mongodb-giving-mongodb-authentication-exception/38607616#38607616)